# installed jenkins on a fresh ubuntu 16.04 server, runs but no website and nothing in logs?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

Jenkins says its running without errors, but when I go to

```
http://myserverip:8080
```

or

```
http://myservername:8080
```

in a browser, it says "This site can’t be reached".

On the server, if I do this:

```
wget http://localhost:8080
```

I get this:

```
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-10-17 02:13:42 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I started it thusly:

```
sudo systemctl start jenkins
```

and got:

```
jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active:active (exited) since Thu 2017-04-20 16:51:13 UTC; 2min 7s ago
    Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

Which is apparently all good and correct.

```
sudo systemctl status jenkins
```

gives:

```
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-10-17 02:01:44 CEST; 13min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Oct 17 02:01:43 bob systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Oct 17 02:01:43 bob jenkins[35278]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Oct 17 02:01:43 bob su[35299]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Oct 17 02:01:43 bob su[35299]: + ??? root:jenkins
Oct 17 02:01:43 bob su[35299]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Oct 17 02:01:44 bob jenkins[35278]:    ...done.
Oct 17 02:01:44 bob systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
Oct 17 02:02:18 bob systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

The FW is open:

```
sudo ufw status
```

gives:

```
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

looking at the log files there are no errors.  e.g.

```
tail -f /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
```

gives:

```
Oct 17, 2017 2:01:57 AM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load
INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller
Oct 17, 2017 2:01:58 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
Oct 17, 2017 2:01:58 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
Oct 17, 2017 2:01:58 AM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load
INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller
Oct 17, 2017 2:01:58 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 6,382 ms
```

if I do

```
ps -ef | grep jenkins
```

I see

```
jenkins  36715     1  0 02:22 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
jenkins  36719 36715  0 02:22 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
jenkins  36726     1  0 02:22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
jenkins  36727 36726 34 02:22 ?        00:00:16 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
```

I just installed it according to the guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Before I installed it, I did the usual:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Any ideas why I cant see jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the issue.
Dediserve has a built in web based external FW for each server.  I just opened 8080 in the dediserve control panel and it works.

I am used to linode which doesn't have such a FW - you have to install your own on each server or it is exposed.